# LED circiuit for a current limited circuit

Tags: power-supply, led, current-limiting

I have the following requirements for a circuit:

1. The circuit is supplied from a 500mA current limited voltage source
2. The circuit should indicate the status of the supply, i.e. if it is in current limit or not with an LED, the LED must be lit when current limit is on and be off when current limit is not active

I am testing the current limit with a 20 Ohm resistor that I am able to switch onto the supply. When I switch in the resistor the current limit is impossed and the source voltage drops to approx. 10V to give 500mA thorugh the resistor. When the resistor is switched out of the circuit the source voltage is 24V.
Placing the LED in parallel with the load gives the correct behaviour, but only a few mA flows through the LED and the light can barely be seen. I need full current to flow in the LED. I tried simulating an 18V Zener in series with the LED and resistor, all in parallel with the load and this works fine, with the exception that the LED is lit when the resistor is switched out and off when switched in (opposite of what I want). I have also tried a resistor divider on the supply voltage and the supply voltage voltage directly into a 24V comparator, but this obviously just scales down the input voltage when current limit is impossed, so this is also a bad solution.
I feel like this should be easily fixed, but I just cant seem to find a smart solution.
Only thing that comes to mind is to incorporate a voltage reference IC to have a fixed voltage into the comparator for comparing with the supply voltage.
Any ideas would be greately appreciated.

Comment: There are thousands of commercially available LED constant current drivers.  Pick one that will work for your application, and then connect your monitoring device to see if the device is outputting the expected voltage for constant current operation.

Comment: I chose a variant of your answer and simply powered the LED from a 5V LDO directly from the supply. Thank you for your input!